# Overflow hidden not working on hover

Tags: html, css

I have this div and I want to show the `title` when I hover over `title` div. The problem is that I get the hover effect even if I hover on the edges of the div. So the div is treated as a square and not as a circle when I hover on it. This works pretty well on Firefox but not on Chrome and Safari.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/roeg629c/2/

Note: I do not want to change the aspect ratio of the image. The image should be `100% of the parent height`.

HTML

```
<div class="video_wrap update" video_name="rikthejmna">
    <div class="related img_wrap"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/XyzYVpJGRG8/hqdefault.jpg"></div>
    <div class="title">rikthejm na</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video_wrap {
    width: 232px;
    height: 232px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 116px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.img_wrap img {height: 100%}

.related {height: 100%;}

.title {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: .5;
    color: #f8008c;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}

.title:hover {opacity: 1}
```

Comment: Generally, what you need to do is add border radius to the `.title` element that will match the `.video_wrap`

Comment: @Alon That makes sense and I thought of it and tried it already, but..... No, it didn't work. Now thinking about it again, of course it wouldn't work otherwise it would've worked already with the current border radius on the main `div`.

Comment: [It's Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218).

Comment: The good and surprising news, it works properly in IE11. The bad news, I tried it on a simple one `div` with border radius and it did not work in Chrome, so I guess it is a Chrome behaviour. I cannot think of any possible workaround except the complex defining a region and events in JavaScript.

Comment: It doesn't work on Safari too. Yes but it would be nicer if we found a css only solution. @RacilHilan

Comment: I know, but I cannot think of any workaround in CSS....... Well.... Perhaps we can do it with an overlay instead of `overflow:hidden`. That will be a bit complex, so give me some time to figure it out.

Comment: I see the same behavior with FF42 and Chrome46 with win10

Comment: Works well on FF42 on El Capitan for me. I can not test in on Win. Sorry

Comment: [Screenshot](http://snag.gy/ct8ON.jpg) of Chrome46 hovered - color changed for better view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avoid positioning of the `.title`, and `opacity`.

```css
.video_wrap{
width: 232px;
height: 232px;
border-radius: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 10px;
}
.related {
width: 232px;
height: 232px;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1;
}
.img_wrap img {
height: 100%;
}
.title{
margin: 185px 0 0;
background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
.title:hover{
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="video_wrap update">
<div class="related img_wrap"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/XyzYVpJGRG8/hqdefault.jpg"></div>
<div class="title">
    rikthejm na
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. So the height of title is achieved by using margins?

Comment: Yes, made the image div absolute and pushed down title by margin